# How can I make Xinu support mouse?

Tags: x86, operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have exercise to do in real time. In my code I am trying to find the mouse interrupt to replace the current one with my function with:

```
for(i=0; i < 32; i++)
    if (sys_imp[i].ivec == 116){
        printf("found it 116");
        sys_imp[i].newisr = new_int116;
        return;
    }
```

and for some reason i cannot find it. After looking in all interrupt vector, it seems Xinu doesn't support mouse .

Any help how i can control interrupt 116?  Do i need to change something in initiali.c?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more, e.g what platform are you running/emulating Xinu for ? (the 2015 version of Xinu doesn't have anything called`sys_imp` , so what's that ?) What is the reasoning behind checking for 116 ?

Comment: i am using old one i think its before 2014 even so, i wanna take over 116 in order to check if mouse left button was pressed\realsed and i wanna save time defferience between the moment he pressed and released.            in order to do that i need to take control on 116 and checking with int 33h .  i am running xinu on doxbox.

Comment: Why do you assume interrupt 116 will let you check the mouse button? The actual hardware interrupt that fires when the mouse is clicked depends on the kind of mouse and how its connected. Serial mice, PS/2 mice and USB mice all use different hardware interrupts. Given the nature of DosBox's emulation it may not be emulating any of these, instead only providing the INT 33h interface. In that case there would be no hardware interrupt that fires when button is pressed.

Comment: i donot want to use interrupt 116 , i need to change the old one with new one that i create and in the new function i will use it for press\release left button for my own need.